# How to disable paralalleism while db2 backup

Tags: db2

Currently when I do a db2 backup I can see `Autonomic backup/restore - using parallelism = 2.` in the logs. How can we disable parallelism so that its at the lowest? I am on DB2 version 11.1.9.0.

Comment: What's the backup target in your case? Disk, TSM?

Comment: Backup target is disk. Actually of them is TSM. Does that matter in case on parallelism?

Comment: According to your output this backup is automatically scheduled, and it seems that we can't set backup parallelism in the backup policy. See the ~db2inst1/sqllib/samples/automaintcfg/DB2AutoBackupPolicySample.xml sample file.

Comment: we have both scheduled as well as manually initiated backups.

Comment: If your true intention is limit the impact of the Db2-backup activities, then consider throttling the backup instead of interfering with parallelism. *Assumes you have relevant instance and database level rights.

Comment: We did try that. But when the db2 backup is in progress the system behaves very weird and many things just get hung up. eg: any bash command we execute.

Comment: I’d suggest you to open a Case with IBM to investigate root cause of these problems. There may be some system problems not related to such a small backup parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `PARALLELISM 1` clause

```
db2 backup database test to /dev/null PARALLELISM 1

Backup successful. The timestamp for this backup image is : 20181105183709

db2diag -H 1m | grep "Autonomic backup"
Autonomic backup/restore - using parallelism = 1.
```

but as you are using Db2 Warehouse, you should use `db_backup` to backup the database https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/admin/app_backup.html

Comment: This doesn't allow backup destination to be cloud.

Comment: Raise a case with IBM to register your need

Comment: If we do not specify PARALLELISM in the command what is the default parallelism? Where can I raise the need?

Comment: > PARALLELISM n  
 Determines the number of table spaces that can be read in parallel by the backup utility. Db2 automatically chooses an optimal value for this parameter unless you explicitly enter a value. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001a933.html?pos=2

Comment: `db2 => PARALLELISM n;
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following 
"PARALLELISM n".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".  
SQLSTATE=42601` The above prallelism link is broken?

Comment: `db2 backup database test to /dev/null PARALLELISM 1`

Comment: but really you need to use  `db_backup`